# Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus

Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differientiable on $(a,b)$. Also $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x) $ exists. Then the question is whether $f$ has a right derivative at point $x=a$.

Here is my tries.

$$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f'(a+t)-f'(a)}{t}=k $$ for $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x) $ exists.
Then consider 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0^+} f'(\xi)=k$$
which $\xi \in(a,a+t)$.
Now we can conclude $f$ has a right derivative at point $x=a$.
Am I right?

Comment: As with just about any basic question about derivatives: Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry,I have edited it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic question on MVT.

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $
\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f'(x)$ exists. As the limit exists, for every sequence that goes downward to $a$, $f'$ converges to that value.

Then we see on the interval $(a,b)$ for any sequence $\{h_n\}$ such that $h_n \rightarrow 0$ after some $N$, we have that $(a,a+h_n) \subset (a,b)$

Consider $\{a + h_k\}_{k=n}^{\infty}$. Then by MVT there is some $\zeta \in (a,a+h_k)$ such that \begin{align} \frac{f(a+h_k)-f(a)}{h_k} = f'(\zeta) \end{align} Then we see as $k \rightarrow \infty$  \begin{align} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a+h_k)-f(a)}{h_k} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f'(x) \end{align} 
where this is justified by the limit existing.And as this was an arbitrary subsequence that converges to $a$, we obtain the claim.